# Show range of numbers based on thousands of records

Tags: excel, numbers, range

I have 15,000 numbers ranging between 1000-8000. Each number is assigned to one of six categories and subcategories, in some cases there are overlaps. *Sample data:*

```
value  cat1    cat2
2333   WHITE   A
2334   ORANGE  B
2335   ORANGE  A
2335   WHITE   B
2336   ORANGE  A
2336   WHITE   B
2336   RED     C
2337   RED     A
2338   RED     A
2339   RED     A
2340   RED     A
```

What's an efficient way of combining these values as such:

- White: 2333, 2335-2336
- Orange: 2334-2335, 2336
- Red: 2336-2340

*Use case:* Given a value such as **2338 A** what is an efficient way of retrieving the cat1 value of **RED**?

For this use case, what would be a more efficient way of storing these strings to test against?

Language preference is JavaScript, PHP or MS Excel

Comment: The records are already in Excel? If you want to use PHP wouldn't it's better to transfer them into a database?

Comment: Currently the numbers are in Excel but can be transferred to MySQL or other format, whatever suits - the storage of the data isn't a factor this can change, the question is as to how to manipulate the data once it is available.

Comment: OK. Is your question "given `cat1` = `Red`" how to output `value` = 2336~2340" or the Use case i.e. "given `2338 A` how to output `cat1` = RED"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems your looking in the wrong place for your solution.

The MOST efficient way to do the type of "retrieving" any variation/combination of your data is to "query" a database.

If it was me I'd dump all my data in MySQL and do simple query from there:

```
$num = 2338
$letter = A
```

SQL:

```
SELECT cat1
FROM dataSet
WHERE value = $num AND catb = $letter
```

Change your search values accordingly.

Comment: yeah I reckon that's how I'll do it. I was thinking initially to have a large array of ranged in JavaScript if MySQL isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Because this question is tagged Excel, I will mention that you can use ADO and Jet to query Excel.